# Geektools Shell Problem

Tags: command-line, sudo, geektool

In order to monitor the filesystem activity on my computer, I found command "sudo fs_usage", which works very well in Terminal. Then I had the idea to display those system activities (written) on my desktop wallpaper.

I downloaded the app "GeekTool" and created a "Shell" widget with the command:

```
echo "root password" | sudo -s fs_usage
```

But it doesn't work :(

Comment: I expect `sudo` doesn't work with GeekTool widgets, as there's nowhere for you to authenticate as root.

Comment: When you say "monitor the activity" do you specifically mean file reads/writes?

Comment: @  Timothy Mueller-Harder - yes, I mean monitoring reads and writes on my hd. I use little snitch to monitor network activity. I did not find any similar app for hd activity; and there are a lot of activity always going on in background I like to know or kill, respectively.

Comment: But you give me also hint for CPU usage and RAM usage. Activity Monitor. iStat has great graphics. But I would like to know where it is, especially folder/source on HD / RAM.

Comment: Try "echo <root password> | sudo -s fs_usage" in your terminal and you don't need to type root password

Comment: Sorry, that wasn't clear before your edit. I would *strongly* recommend against storing your password in plaintext anywhere on your computer, though, even if that method did work.

Comment: `sudo` requires the password of the current account, not the root password. But: In Terminal, if you run `sudo -k` (remove credentials) followed by `echo <password> | sudo -s fs_usage`, does it still work without having to type your password?

Answer (score 2):

You can circumvent the need to enter a password to use `fs_usage` by means of the `sudoers` file.

**Warning:** I am not a security expert in any way, and modification of the `sudoers` file should only be performed with extreme caution. I don't *think* this particular solution would be a security issue, but again, I’m not an expert.

1. Open Terminal, type `sudo visudo`, and enter your password.
2. Scroll down using the arrow keys to the “User privilege specification” section.
3. Look for a line that starts with your username, or failing that, one that starts with `%admin`.
4. Position the cursor just below that line and press <kbd>A</kbd> to enter insert mode.
5. Add the following text on its own line:

   ```
   yourusername ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/fs_usage
   ```
6. Press <kbd>esc</kbd>, then type `:wq` <kbd>enter</kbd> to save your changes and quit.

You will need to restart GeekTool. I don’t think you need to reboot for the changes to take effect, but if it doesn’t work, try that.

Comment: This is a much better idea than putting your password into your Geek Tool shell widget.  ★

Comment: Ok, I accidentally deleted unrecoverable my sudoers file. What now?

Comment: How.... It should be ok if you follow these instructions carefully.

Comment: Oops, I forgot to link the thing I meant to! https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/74145